# Couldn't match expected type Int against inferred type Integer

Tags: haskell, inferred-type

I have written some simple haskell function to compute the neighbours of a given vertex in a graph (see below). It compiles fine, however, when I run `adj g 1`, I get the following error: `` Couldn't match expected type `Int' against inferred type `Integer' ``

The code:

```
module Test where
import Prelude
import Data.List


type Node = Int
type Edge = (Int, Int)

type Graph = ([Node], [Edge])

g = ([1,2,3,4,5,6], [(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(5,6)])


adj :: Graph -> Node -> [Node]
adj (vs, []) n = []
adj (vs,((s,e):es)) n   | s==n = e:rec
                        | e==n = s:rec
                        | otherwise = rec
    where
    rec = adj (vs,es) n
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an explicit type signature:

```
g :: ([Int], [(Int, Int)])
```

or better still

```
g :: Graph
```

This happens because numbers like `7` can be any integral type, and it defaults to Integer, whereas your functions use Int.

Comment: Could you not write `g :: Graph`?

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster Could I not write what?

Comment: Yes, I popped that in as you were writing!

Comment: Heh, sorry, didn't remember that hitting enter posted the comment. OK, cool!

Comment: You wouldn't believe how often that happens when I'm on SO on my mobile. So frustrating.